# Reserved namespaces for custom directives in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a use case where I need to manually compile directives using the $compiler service.

I was trying to manually compile the following: `<tr-item item="item"></tr-item>`.  After correctly calling $compile with the correct scope, no element was returned.

After some investigation, I noticed that if I replaced `tr-item` with `tr_item`, I started getting a valid element from the $compile service.

Finally, I switched  the namespace from `tr-item` to `my-item`, and noticed that with a namespace of "my" both dashed and underscore syntax worked.

I have created a plunker to showcase the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/kOv7oFnukZxHMEi3xasF

Is "tr" a reserved namespace?  If the answer is yes, then why is it reserved?

I tried other namespaces that match html elements and "td" has the same problem, but "div" works normally.

I'd appreciate any insight into this!

Comment: Tried your plunker all three examples are working as expected.  tr is not reserved, and does not make a difference.

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: pixelbits, if you look at the plunker I test 4 different use cases.  Only 3 of them get rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$compile` will use jqLite to convert DOM element to JQuery element at first, refer to this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1179

and jqLite will map some reserved tag like `tr`, `thead`, `td`, etc to comprehensive tag name, refer to this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js#L153

try to compile your directive as attribute, but better to avoid using these kind of reserved tag names.

Comment: Thanks for showing me what was causing it.  I dove a little deeper and this happens mainly due to a bug dealing with a regular expression in jqLite (and jQuery).  I just sent a patch over if you're interested in following it: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/10619

Comment: cool, i have raised this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10617) at first time, looks like someone else has also pulled a request based on this right ahead of you: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/10618. but still need further check on JQuery